# How is Floating-point arithmetic implemented?

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

In the book - **Linux Device Drivers**, the author says the kernel code cannot do floating arithmetic at page 42. How does operating system do floating arithmetic without being supported by the kernel?
I think, probably, I misunderstand the author. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Pretty good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886338/use-of-floating-point-in-the-linux-kernel