# What's the best way to calculate log(base2) of any number?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to find log(base2) of any number in Linux kernel programming.
Is there any built in function for this operation?
If not how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's enough for you an integer result, you can divide multiple times by 2. Something like

```
int logFunc(unsigned int x) 
{ 
   int log = -1; 
   while(x) { 
    log++; 
    x >>= 1; 
   } 
   return log; 
}
```

If you need fp ops, you should read this:

> [...]if the question was "can I just use FP in the kernel" then the
>   answer is still a resounding NO, since other architectures may not
>   support it AT ALL.
>
> ```
>   Linus
> ```
>
> [Link](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/kernel_fp.html)

Also, you can take a look to: [Use of floating point in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886805/3315914)

EDIT: If you need a faster version you can read [Bit Twiddling Hacks - By Sean Eron Anderson](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)

```
uint32_t v; // find the log base 2 of 32-bit v
int r;      // result goes here

static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

v |= v >> 1; // first round down to one less than a power of 2 
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;

r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Comment: a good way of dividing by two quickly here is `>>` do a binary search for the largest bit set to `1` of your unsigned int.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your comment. I've added a resource with good implementations about this.

Comment: Those solutions work well to find log(base2) of integer numbers. But I also need to find log(base2) of non integers.

Comment: That's problematic. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to find the value corresponding to clock frequency.
Your method works if the frequency can be expressed as a power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the logarithm of a number N in any particular base B is equal to `log(N)/log(B)`, where `log()` can be either the natural logarithm (base `e`), or any other base (e.g. base 10), as long as both `log(N)` and `log(B)` are calculated with respect to the same base.

Comment: Which header file to include?

Comment: This is for the Linux kernel code though. I don't believe there's a math header...