# Using float, double arithmeetic causes warnings on arm

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gcc-warning

I have a device driver which was compiling fine using arm-linux-gnueabi-
I added a few double and float operations into the code and I have been getting the following warnings at compilation:

WARNING: "__aeabi_dsub" [/home/preetam/Desktop/pwm_driver/driver/pwm_dev.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__aeabi_d2uiz" [/home/preetam/Desktop/pwm_driver/driver/pwm_dev.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__aeabi_dmul" [/home/preetam/Desktop/pwm_driver/driver/pwm_dev.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__aeabi_ddiv" [/home/preetam/Desktop/pwm_driver/driver/pwm_dev.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__aeabi_ui2d" [/home/preetam/Desktop/pwm_driver/driver/pwm_dev.ko] undefined!

Does it mean that the compiler and/or the arm platform does not support floating and double data types?

How do I deal with this situation. I need to be able to do the math to get the proper functionality.

Comment: Can you do your floating point operations in user space?  Floating point operations in kernel space are highly discouraged.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886338/use-of-floating-point-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: You must not use FP in the kernel. Show what your driver is actually trying to do.

Comment: It a pwm driver. The user just wants to give frequency and duty cycle and I need to calculate the time based on that. The user here does not want to do those conversions in userspace. That's my problem.