# OpenCL/C pow(x,0.5) != sqrt(x)

Tags: c, opencl, pyopencl

I guess I am in some really strange border case, maybe with double precision issues and I want to know, whats going on.

Inside an OpenCL Kernel I use:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

__private int k = 2; // I need k to be an int, because I want to use as a counter
__private double s = 18;
__private double a = 1;

a = a/(double)k; // just to show, that I make in-place typecasting of k
a = k+1;
k = (int)a; //to show that I store k in a double buffer in an intermediate-step
if ((k-1)==2)
{
//    k = 3;
    s = pow(s/(double)(k-1),0.5);
}
```

This leads me to `s = 2.999[...]6`
However, if I uncomment the `k=3` line, I get the (in my eyes) correct result `s = 3`. Why is that?

As a side information: The same behaviour doesn't happen when I do

```
s = sqrt(s/(double)(k-1))
```

Below follows the full, minimal Kernel and Host code for pyopencl

Kernel (Minima.cl):

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

__kernel void init_z(__global double * buffer)
{
    __private int x = get_global_id(0);
    __private int y = get_global_id(1);
    //w,h
    __private int w_y = get_global_size(1);
    __private int address = x*w_y+y;
    //h,w
    __private double init = 3.0;
    buffer[address]=init;
}

__kernel void root(__global double * buffer)
{
    __private int x = get_global_id(0);
    __private int y = get_global_id(1);
    //w,h
    __private int w_y = get_global_size(1);
    __private int address = x*w_y+y;
    //h,w
    __private double value = 18;
    __private int k;
    __private double out;
    k = (int) buffer[address];
  //k = 3;  If this line is uncommented, the result will be exact.
    out = pow(value/(double)(k-1), 0.5);
    buffer[address] = out;
}
```

Host:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np


platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
devs = platform.get_devices()
device1 = devs[1]
h_buffer = np.empty((10,10)).astype(np.float64)
mf = cl.mem_flags
ctx = cl.Context([device1])
Queue1 = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
Queue2 = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
mf = cl.mem_flags
m_dic = {0:mf.READ_ONLY,1:mf.WRITE_ONLY,2:mf.READ_WRITE}


fi = open('Minimal.cl', 'r')
fstr = "".join(fi.readlines())
prg = cl.Program(ctx, fstr).build()
knl = prg.init_z
knl.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([None,])
knl_root = prg.root
knl_root.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([None,])



def f():
    d_buffer =  cl.Buffer(ctx,m_dic[2], int(10 * 10  * 8))
    knl.set_args(d_buffer)
    knl_root.set_args(d_buffer)
    a = cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(Queue2,knl,(10,10),None)
    b = cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(Queue2,knl_root,(10,10),None, wait_for = [a,])
    cl.enqueue_copy(Queue1,h_buffer,d_buffer,wait_for=[b,])
    return h_buffer
a = f()
a[0,0] # Getting the result on the host.
```

**Edit:** Because of some more unclarities I update this question one more time. I understand, that the value of `pow` and `sqrt` doesn't have to be the same for the same input. My question is, why `pow` shows different output for the SAME input, depending on where I get it from.

The binaries are on pastebin:
[k_explicit](http://pastebin.com/fHnZtQCH) and [k_read](http://pastebin.com/p4nnD6H7)

`printf("a%\n", out)` leads to `0x1.8p+1` with the `k=3` line and to `0x1.7ffffffffffffp+1` when it's commented out.

Comment: R7-240 gives 3 for both situations. it could be that device's compiler's doing optimizations. something like putting the number 3 directly there since all can be known in compile time

Comment: I don't see an error there. s = s+-epsilon everything is fine. Thats how floating point works.

Comment: Actually k is not known at compile time. During Kernel calls k is written-to and read-from a double-buffer to implement a counter which is persistent over kernel calls.

Comment: @KamiKaze: That doesn't answer the question why for the same input the answer is different.

Comment: @Dschoni I tried with buffers this time(so no compile time optimizations), again it prints 3 for both cases. Maybe something to do with rounding modes? https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/SELECT_ROUNDING_MODE.html

Comment: I'm on a nvidia Titan X. Rounding modes could be possible. Is there any way to verify?

Comment: `pow` is much more general than `sqrt` and therefore almost certain to have worse accuracy when asked to do `sqrt`'s job.

Comment: Is [Use of floating point in the Linux kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886338/use-of-floating-point-in-the-linux-kernel) relevant?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm not entirely sure. Because context switching seems not to be the issue here. I'll try and write a self-contained kernel to deploy on different architectures to see and compare if hardware is an issue.

Comment: The general advice in that link seems to be: avoid using FPU in the kernel.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Different concept of "kernel". The issues of using the FPU/Vector registers in an OS kernel do not apply for CUDA/openCL kernels.

Comment: I added a completely self-contained example that shows the behaviour.

Comment: could you look at nvidia control panel? there must be some setting near where you enable/disable fp64 cores

Comment: it says "Optimize for Compute Performance Off, On Windows 10, Maxwell
GPUs and later.
Offers significant
improvement for some
Compute applications.
Care should be taken
when turning this
setting ON, as there can
be unpredictable
effects with some
applications and
graphics features." as in here: http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/378.49/378.49-nvidia-control-panel-quick-start-guide.pdf

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: "This leads me to s = 2.999[...]6" is not as useful as posting the code that printed it.  Suggest `printf("%a\n", s);`  At least then we would see _exactly_ what  2.999[...]6 is.  Likely the same as `printf("%.16f\n", nextafter(3,0));`

Comment: @KamiKaze FP does not work to "s = s+-epsilon everything is fine", but to "s = s*(1 +/- epsilon) everything is fine".

Comment: @Dschoni Does `printf("%a\n", sqrt(9));` and `printf("%a\n", pow(9,0.5));` produce the same result?

Comment: `pow(double, double)` has minimum 16ulp so this is to be expected

Comment: Because of some strange printing issue of Nvidia (oh, how I hate them and their OpenCL policy...), I get my results in python on the host as a[0,0]. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @chux: `printf("a%\n", out)` leads to `0x1.8p+1` with the `k=3` line and to `0x1.7ffffffffffffp+1` without it.

Comment: @Dschoni  The answers are within 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of each other and your platform is simply using a lower performing `pow()`.  Buy a better compiler/math library.

Comment: @chux AKA use an AMD implementation. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots of discussion it doesn't seem to be a problem with my code. The behaviour seems to be hardware-dependent and so far only reproducable on Nvidia Hardware. I'm still interested in the "why" and "how" that happens but in this case the question is answered.

Answer (score 4):

Floating point calculations are not exact.  So using one algorithm (`sqrt`) and a different one (`pow()`) with the same inputs cannot be expected to give bitwise-identical results.  If both results are within ±epsilon of the mathematically true value, then both implementations are acceptable.

Typically, `pow()` is implemented in terms of `ln()` and `exp()` (with a multiplication in between), whereas `sqrt()` can use a much faster implementation (which probably involves halving the mantissa as a first step).

Comment: we forgot to ask him which digit changes. there is only `s = 2.999[...]6` which could be 10th digit. khronos site says half_powr computes with ulp of 8192.

Comment: Ln is 4 ulp at most. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.1-environment.pdf

Comment: Again, this doesn't answer the question. In both cases, `k=3`. So with the same input to the same function (`pow`) I get two different results. Whereas with `sqrt` I get the same results. The difference only lies in where I get my `k` from. If I set it explicitly to 3, everything is fine. If I read in k from my array, it shows that behaviour.

Comment: @Dschoni You definitely don't know how evil an OpenCL driver can be. You'd better paste the compiled IL or ISA code.

Comment: I'll look into that and will deliver. So far I tried that on different devices and drivers and see the same behaviour everywhere. Although I didn't find the time to try on AMD devices yet ;)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik it's 2.9999999999999996 (15 times 9)

Comment: @Dschoni 2.9999999999999996 should be fine since average decimal digits are 16 and pow having several ulps. Its just that gpu not obeying same ulp while not crossing limit ulp for both cases

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik still, that doesn't answer why it behaves differently for the same input. I added the link to binaries.

Comment: _which probably involves halving the mantissa as a first step_ - Should that be the exponent?

Comment: @Dschoni - with your `k=3`, you're probably not using the same implementation of `pow` - I would expect that your compiler is optimising the call down to a constant.  There's nothing to force the compiler's internal implementation to be bit-identical with that in the run-time library, as long as they both produce results within the acceptable range of error.  Maybe you shouldn't even have mentioned `sqrt()` if that wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: my cheapest amd card is working fine so it must be implementation defined optimization.

Comment: You are right, maybe this is confusig people. However as mentioned in my question `sqrt()` doesn't have this problem so I thought it could be worth mentioning.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Can you confirm, that on your AMD card, my code is producing exactly 3.0 in both cases?

Comment: I tested it now both on my Xeon CPU and my AMD 'Hawaii' Generation Card. Both work exactly as expected and return exactly 3.0 for all cases. So definitely implementation defined optimization. Again....NVIDIA....

Comment: @Dschoni I'm trying convert_double_rte convert_double_rtz convert_double_rtn instead of (double) to be sure

Comment: @Dschoni exactly 3 for all cases. with explicit convert or simple casting, all same

Comment: @BlueWanderer: Just for the record. Binaries are up there on pastebin. If that gives any further inside. I can only say one is a lot longer than the other :)